# Adding JQuery validation script to header causes the action methods to fire twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On any MVC sample application , adding    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryVal") to the header causes the action method on any link to execute twice.

I have put down the sample header for reference.  Can some explain why this might happen ?
 If I remove the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryVal") tag, action methods behave fine.

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Cool Blogger</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryVal")
    </head>
```

Comment: Have you checked for double references? You might still be referencing the JqueryVal bundle somewhere else in the App? Look at the HTML source (in debug mode) and search for any of the jquery validation files to see if they appear twice.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look and check for double references, look at the developer tools under chrome to see if the script loaded twice, or if you have any error in console mention that the error occurs, you can also see the binding on each element in chrome developer console (F12)